# How to use the RegLoadKey function to load the NTUSER.DAT file from the Default User?

Tags: c++, function, winapi, registry

I thought I could use the RegLoadKey to load the NTUSER.DAT file located in the C:\Users\Default folder by using this code:

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey = L"software\\Load";
    LPCTSTR lpFile = L"C:\\Users\\Default\\NTUSER";

    long R=RegLoadKey(hKey, lpSubKey, lpFile);
```

It did not work. Can anyone tell me how I have to use this function to load the **NTUSER.DAT** file into the **HKLM\Software\Load** sub-key?

Thanks!

Comment: What not work? Which error returns GetLastError? Do you have priviligies enabled? Also in your code you are trying load NTUSER not NTUSER.dat.

Comment: The .dat file does not load. I tries with the full name as well. How do I enable privileges? Thanks!

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/882195-privileges-registry-editting

Answer (score 1):

As @Xearinox mentioned you need privilages (`SE_BACKUP_NAME` and `SE_RESTORE_NAME`)

Also you must load `NTUSER.DAT`, otherwise you create new registry hive. And `lpSubKey` only can be first level after `hKey`.

So you should set privilages and load it like this:

```
long ret = RegLoadKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"LOAD", L"C:\\Users\\Default\\NTUSER.DAT");
```